How to expand a \def content in advance?
Take the following code as an example:
\documentclass{article}
\def\myvar{\fpeval{2+3}}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\in@{5}{54}\ifin@ Yes\else No\fi,
\def\zz{\in@{5}}
\expandafter\zz\expandafter{\myvar}\ifin@ Yes\else No\fi

\makeatother

\end{document}

How to make typesets Yes, Yes?  Most syntax from How to force-expand a \def for \in@?

It works as expected.  Thanks a lot !

egreg's is better. ;-)

\myvar and \fpeval are expandable but getting the rsult requires more than one expansion step while \expandafter triggers only one expansion step. Try s.th. like \expandafter\zz\expandafter{\expanded{\myvar}}\ifin@ Yes\else No\fi or \expandafter\zz\expanded{{\myvar}}\ifin@ Yes\else No\fi or \expanded{\noexpand\zz{\myvar}}\ifin@ Yes\else No\fi.

Seems the sequence of tokens passed on as argument to \zz/passed on as second argument to \in@ is to be obtained in the stage of expansion. But with macros where looking ahead at the next token of the token stream is to take place (\test looks ahead for [ of optional argument) this is not possible as TeX's primitive routines for looking ahead (\fuurelet or \afterassignment..\let) that under the hood are called by \@ifnextchar all involve performing temporary assignments to scratch-macros while performing assignments takes place in processing stages subsequent to expansion.

thanks for your detailed illumination.

Make sure \fpeval is fully evaluated at the time of defining the macro \myvar. Then applying a single expansion step on the macro-token \myvar - as is done by \expandafter - is sufficient for obtaining the tokens that form the value. You can use good old \edef or \ExpandArgs for this.
\documentclass{article}
\edef\myvar{\fpeval{2+3}}
%\ExpandArgs{Ne}\newcommand\myvar{\fpeval{2+3}}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\in@{5}{54}\ifin@ Yes\else No\fi,
\def\zz{\in@{5}}
\expandafter\zz\expandafter{\myvar}\ifin@ Yes\else No\fi

\makeatother

\end{document}


If you like, you can avoid defining \zz by having TeX expand things and flip macro arguments around to get tokens into desired order:
\documentclass{article}
\edef\myvar{\fpeval{2+3}}
%\ExpandArgs{Ne}\newcommand\myvar{\fpeval{2+3}}

\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\in@{5}{54}\ifin@ Yes\else No\fi,
\expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\myvar}{\in@{5}}%
\ifin@ Yes\else No\fi

\makeatother

\end{document}

Using this method or similar methods, you can get the result of expanding tokens behind an arbitrary amount of other tokens.

You need full expansion, not just one level.
\documentclass{article}
\def\myvar{\fpeval{2+3}}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\in@{5}{54}\ifin@ Yes\else No\fi,
\def\zz{\in@{5}}
\expandafter\zz\expanded{{\myvar}}\ifin@ Yes\else No\fi

\in@{5}{54}\ifin@ Yes\else No\fi,
\ExpandArgs{ne}\in@{5}{\myvar}\ifin@ Yes\else No\fi

\makeatother

\end{document}

The latter version is much clearer, isn't it?
Even better:
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\myvar}{\fpeval{2+3}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\IfInTF}{mmmm}
 {% #1 = token list to find, #2 = token list to check against
  % #3 = text if match, #4 = text if no match
  \xcn_ifin:nnnn {#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\IfInExpTF}{mmmm}
 {% #1 = token list to find, #2 = token list to check against
  % #3 = text if match, #4 = text if no match
  \xcn_ifin:nenn {#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \xcn_ifin:nnnn
 {
  \tl_if_in:nnTF {#2}{#1}{#3}{#4}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \xcn_ifin:nnnn {ne}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\IfInTF{5}{54}{Yes}{No},
\IfInExpTF{5}{\myvar}{Yes}{No}

\end{document}

